# How updated is the HTTPS Everywhere list?

Tags: tls

I was wondering if the `HTTPS Everywhere` extension by `EFF` is updated at all. Looking over their extension [page](https://github.com/nullishzero/https-everywhere/tree/master/src/chrome/content/rules) on `Github`, it appears that the list (containing the rules) hasn't been updated since 2014. So, excluding the rules that the user can add themselves, isn't this terribly outdated? Does anyone have any idea whether I am looking at an older list, or whether this is indeed the definitive list currently being used in browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at someone's fork. https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere is very frequently updated, with [131 commits the last week](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pulse).